# Capturar a data da criação do ficheiro

Tags: javascript

Estou a implementar uma ferramenta de upload de ficheiro por FTP na web, uso o *input type file*.

O POST é feito via JavaScript, mas queria saber como faço para saber a data da criação do ficheiro de origem.

Ex.: **file.exe** criado em 2016  é este o valor que quero e não o valor que vai no temp é possível ir buscar a data com o JavaScript depois de selecionar o ficheiro? Antes de usar o Curl para upload do ficheiro?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A data de criação propriamente dita não tem como recuperar, pelo menos não "nativamente".

Porém, é possível recuperar a data da última modificação do arquivo, usando a propriedade **`lastModifiedDate`**.

```js
function clickButton(){
  var files = document.getElementById('input-file').files;
  
  for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++)
    console.log(files[i].lastModifiedDate);
}

document.getElementById('bt-info').addEventListener('click', clickButton);
```

```html
<input type="file" id="input-file" /> <br>

<button id="bt-info">Informações</button>
```

Comment: obrigado pela ajuda